Dynamically lateral flatten in Snowflake
{
  "explosives_UG":{
   "isCritical": false,
   "value": "N/A"
  },
  "explosivesUG": {
   "comment": "Test 619 313",
   "createWo": false,
   "isCritical": false,
   "value": "No"
  },
  "generalAttachment": null,
  "generalComment": "Test 619 313",
  "guardsPostedUG": {
    "isCritical": false,
    "value": "Yes"
  },
  "imminentUG": {
    "isCritical": false,
    "value": "Yes"
  }
}

using the above JSON format, output is generated as below via Snowflake query
question        answer
explosives_UG   N/A
explosivesUG    No
guardsPostedUG  Yes
imminentUG      Yes

SELECT 
  kv.key AS question,
  kv.value:value AS answer
FROM 
  json_data,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => json_col) kv
WHERE 
  kv.key IN ('explosives_UG', 'explosivesUG', 'guardsPostedUG', 'imminentUG');

Question : We will be getting lot of questions/answers and handling them manually in the code is time consuming..
How to use dynamically extract JSON values using LATERAL FLATTEN, can somebody help please...

so if we slam that JSON into a single flatten:
with cte_json_data as (
select 
    PARSE_JSON('
    {
  "explosives_UG":{
   "isCritical": false,
   "value": "N/A"
  },
  "explosivesUG": {
   "comment": "Test 619 313",
   "createWo": false,
   "isCritical": false,
   "value": "No"
  },
  "generalAttachment": null,
  "generalComment": "Test 619 313",
  "guardsPostedUG": {
    "isCritical": false,
    "value": "Yes"
  },
  "imminentUG": {
    "isCritical": false,
    "value": "Yes"
  }
}') as json
)
select
    m.key as questions
    ,m.value
from cte_json_data as j
    ,table(flatten(input=>j.json)) as m

we get:

and you want "it appears" the objects that have a known object, thus we can use IS_NULL_VALUE:
with cte_json_data as (
select 
    PARSE_JSON('
    {
  "explosives_UG":{
   "isCritical": false,
   "value": "N/A"
  },
  "explosivesUG": {
   "comment": "Test 619 313",
   "createWo": false,
   "isCritical": false,
   "value": "No"
  },
  "generalAttachment": null,
  "generalComment": "Test 619 313",
  "guardsPostedUG": {
    "isCritical": false,
    "value": "Yes"
  },
  "imminentUG": {
    "isCritical": false,
    "value": "Yes"
  }
}') as json
)
select
    m.key as questions
    ,m.value:value as answer
from cte_json_data as j
    ,table(flatten(input=>j.json)) as m
where is_null_value(m.value:isCritical) = false;


would appear to do what you are after.

Thank you for your time and reply, 1 doubt..
shift  Day is not coming in the ouput, can you please help what needs to get the data...
"shift": {
"selectedData": {
"id": "D",
"value": "Day"
},
"selectedText": "Day"
}

Iam using the below SQL query
select
m.key as questions
,m.value:value as answer
from cte_json_data as j
,table(flatten(input=>j.json)) as m
where is_null_value(m.value:value) = false;

it is rather clear you are not understanding anything about the relationship between the JSON data and the structure of the SQL being used. Because your new question is like "I have four values 1,2,-3,4 when I use WHERE value >=0 the value -3 does not show up"
